# Unity Spawning Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to spawn a prefab using script. This is the code, the code is written inside the game panel.

```
Network.Instantiate (ninjaPreFab, new Vector3 (-53, -34, 0), Quaternion.identity, 0);
```

However, it is not spawning within the canvas. Instead it always spawn outside of the canvas which mean it's not a child of the canvas, thus not appearing inside the game as I'm using Rendering - Overlay Camera. I've tried setting the Sort Order for the canvas to be -1 but still it doesn't work. I know it spawned because the editor clearly show that there is this new object.

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/instantiating-prefab-with-canvas.266532/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I wasn't supposed to spawn game object/sprite inside the canvas. Canvas is only meant for UI.

Answer (score 2):

If using the new Unity UI, GUI elements must be a child of the canvas gameobject and their coordinates must be set within the boundaries of the canvas and not too close to the camera near-clipping plane (within the viewing frustum) if they are to be visible on screen.  If working with the UI canvas, have a look at the awesome Unity UI tutorials [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-canvas).

As per your snippet of code, it appears your UI elements are invisible because of the negative sign on the coordinate values.  Try changing them to positive values and see what happens.  Also, parent the UI element to the canvas like this:

```
var newUIElement = Network.Instantiate (ninjaPreFab, new Vector3 (53, 34, 0), Quaternion.identity, 0);
newUIElement.transform.parent = canvas;
```

Comment: This would only ensure the one that is spawning the ui element will see the new ui element. For example, when the server spawn it, only the server will be able to view the ui element, the client doesn't get to see it.

Comment: Problem solved. I wasn't supposed to spawn game object/sprite inside the canvas. Canvas is only meant for UI.